# I am getting the error in react native - fontFamily "ionicons" is not a system font

Tags: react-native

I am getting the following error in react native - fontFamily "ionicons" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync.

- If you intended to use a system font, make sure you typed the name correctly and that it is supported by your device operating system.

I am trying to import the expo vector icons.

```
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
```

and using the icon

```
<Button transparent>
    <Ionicons name="md-checkmark-circle" size={32} color="green" />
</Button>
```

but getting the above mentioned error.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Another possible solution I happened upon after of hours of looking at code that should work and which is identical to the sample and the excellent previous answer.

If you have been upgrading Expo this may be your answer.

1. Delete node_modules
2. Delete package-lock.json
3. run `expo install`
4. run `expo start -c`

Comment: Jeez, out of all the answers, this one actually worked. Thank you. I thought I was going crazy.

Comment: Thank you! This was driving me nuts. Sometimes you sit down to work on your app for a few hours and end up turning everything off and on for a few hours instead. Greatly appreciate the answer.

Comment: If you just upgraded Expo, this is the verified answer!

Comment: which Expo version supporting this? For me expo install not worked

Comment: Thanks this worked for me also! Good to know for future debugging issues also.

Comment: this saved me 'hours of looking at code' thanks. what happened is I did 'npm install' new package and somehow it broke.

Answer (score 9):

If nuking `node_modules` is not working, then make sure you don't have installed multiple versions of `expo-font`.

1. Remove `expo-font` from `node_modules/expo/node_modules/expo-font/`.
2. Remove `expo-font` form list of dependencies from `node_modules/expo/package.json`.
3. Run `expo r -c`

For details [Expo cannot load a font due to multiple versions of `expo-font` installed](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/5507#issuecomment-535067703).

Comment: This was the issue for me. Using `pnpm` package manager. `expo` depends on `expo-font` and my app depended on `expo-font` too. They were resolving to different versions.

Comment: Make sure you install `expo` related packages using command `expo install`.

Answer (score 3):

The library `@expo/vector-icons`  is only installed by default on the template project that get through `expo init --` it is part of the expo package .

If you created your project using `react-native init` use `react-native-vector-icons` instead

**Installation**

```
npm i react-native-vector-icons

react-native link react-native-vector-icons
```

**Usage**

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

<Button transparent>
    <Icon name="md-checkmark-circle" size={32} color="green" />
</Button>
```

**OR**

try loading Ionicons using `Font.loadAsync` in your `App.js`

```
async componentDidMount () {
    await Expo.Font.loadAsync({
        Ionicons: require('@expo/vector-icons/fonts/Ionicons.ttf'),
    });
```

Comment: i am not using any font in the code then why its showing that fontFamily "ionicons" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync. if i remove  <Ionicons name="md-checkmark-circle" size={32} color="green" /> then code is working absolutely fine...

Comment: how you created your project using expo cli or react native cli ?

Comment: I have created it using expo cli

Comment: Try loading the fonts in your app.js .. using Font.loadAsync

Answer (score 1):

Adding `Iconicons` in `loadAsync` solved this bug for me.

```
async componentDidMount () {
    await Expo.Font.loadAsync({
        Ionicons: require('@expo/vector-icons/fonts/Ionicons.ttf'),
    });
```

Comment: Expo.Font was what I missed, I was doing Font.loadAsync alone. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by removing `<Icon\>` tag in my code.

After leaving only `<Ionicons\>` tags for icons, I got saved.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue by `expo upgrade` just in case anyone else would see that.

Comment: It is an answer and it might help people Zeeshan Ali. Scroll up to the top answer and view the comment about using `expo upgrade` it got 3 upvotes meaning it helped people.

Comment: This is actually what ended up doing it for me. I had upgraded my version of expo cli and expo and must have had incompatible versions. `expo upgrade` seems to have fixed any incompatibilities and resolved this error for me. None of the above suggestions had worked.

Answer (score 0):

None of the suggestions worked for me. I found the ionicons.ttf file [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionicons/blob/main/docs/fonts/ionicons.ttf), downloaded and copied it to my fonts folder and linked it this way:

```
 let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
        'Ionicons': require('./assets/fonts/ionicons.ttf'),
      });
    
      if (!fontsLoaded) {
        return ( ... );
      } else {
    
        return ( ... )
    }
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

This led me to my solution. Was getting the error and my fonts were in Chinese characters. All I did was `yarn install expo-font` and it worked

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was running:

npx expo install --fix

For installing new packages avoid using *npm install package_name* but use:

npx expo install package_name

Answer (score -1):

1. Remove `expo-font` from `package.json`.
2. delete `node_modules` and `package.lock.json` .
3. Run `npm install`  or `yarn install`
4. Run `npm start` or `yarn start`.