# font-family "ionicons" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fonts, expo, native-base

I am using native-base UI framework for react-native.  I am having same error again and again even I'm not using 'Ionicons' anywhere in my project.   I tried to delete node_modules and running `npm install` but it didn't work.
I also tried example solution given by native-base team, on github [here](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase-KitchenSink). And also solution by Expo 
on [Using custom fonts - Expo](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/using-custom-fonts/).  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZzhg.png) 
But nothing worked for me.
After trying different things it turned out that custom fonts used by native-base are not being loaded.  I've tried to load it through `Font.loadAsync` but it is not working.

```js
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import { AppLoading } from 'expo';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import App from '../App.js';

const roboto = require('../../assets/fonts/Roboto.ttf');
const robotoMedium = require('../../assets/fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf');
const ionicons = require('../../assets/fonts/Ionicons.ttf');

export default class Setup extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isReady: false,
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.loadFonts();
  }

  async loadFonts() {
    try {
      await Font.loadAsync({
        Roboto: roboto,
        Roboto_medium: robotoMedium,
        Ionicons: ionicons,
      });
      this.setState({ isReady: true });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.isReady) {
      return <AppLoading />;
    }
    return <App />;
  }
}
```

Comment: i've got solution at [expo can't load font because of multiple versions of expo-font](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/5507)

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59798584/10547792